# how to save .config to ./arch/arm/configs/ in linux kernel configuration

Tags: linux, configuration, kernel

I have configuring the **linux kernel 3.4**. I have the defconfig file supplied by the chip vendor. I have applied the defconfig and then changed some more configuration using the menuconfig. Now i have the updated .config file.

I need to save this `.config` file into `./arch/arm/configs/` so that in future no need to redo the configurations I already did.

Thanks and Regards, 
Giri

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy the .config manually to ./arch/arm/configs/(and probably add it to your version control also)

```
cp .config ./arch/arm/configs/CUSTOM_defconfig
```

And when you need to load this configuration just use:

```
make CUSTOM_defconfig
```

Comment: is there any other way to do it? i mean during the menuconfig itself can we save it to arch/arm/configs/CUSTOM_config

Answer (score 1):

You can use buildroot utility to save your defconfig file using :

`$> make savedefconfig`

Then, you can find a file named "defconfig" in the same location of your .config file.